# Filter name MustHaveTenant not found

Tags: entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I use ABP, and I am getting an error:

> Filter name MustHaveTenant not found

I don't need multiple tenants.

I checked the ABP document, and I did use this code:

```cs
Configuration.UnitOfWork.OverrideFilter(AbpDataFilters.MustHaveTenant, false);
```

But I still get the error.

[image]

DbContext code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>().Property(t => t.RequestId).HasMaxLength(50); 
    modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>().Property(t => t.Method).HasMaxLength(20); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't need to use MiltiTenancy you can turn it off on your ProyectCoreModule

```
        Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = PuntoVentaConsts.MultiTenancyEnabled;
```

In this line you can change it to `false` or change the const property value to `false`

And you're getting the filter error because you omitted the call to

`base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` in your `OnModelCreating()` method, it has to be like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>().Property(t => t.RequestId).HasMaxLength(50); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>().Property(t => t.Method).HasMaxLength(20); 
    }
```